# Liveness probe with http post

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm running a web service that I can not change any of the specifications. I want to use liveness probe with HTTP POST on Kubernetes. I couldn't find anything available. All of my efforts with busybox and netcat have failed.

Is there a solution? Is it possible to build a custom liveness probe from any Linux dist?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Kubernetes Probes only support HTTP GET, TCP & Command.

If you must check something over HTTP POST you could use a command approach and just `curl -XPOST ..`

An example would be:

```
...
      containers:
        - name:  k8-byexamples-spring-rest
          image: gcr.io/matthewdavis-byexamples/k8-byexamples-spring-rest:1d4c1401c9485ef61322d9f2bb33157951eb351f
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              name: http
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - curl
                - -X POST
                - http://localhost/test123
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 5
...
```

For more explanation see: https://matthewdavis.io/kubernetes-health-checks-demystified/.

Hope that helps!

Comment: You may want to use `curl --fail -X POST ...` if you would like to exit on any non success error codes such as 500. 

Otherwise, the `curl` command still exits with a zero error code for non-success error codes, and the liveness or readiness probe will not be deemed to have failed by Kubernetes.

Comment: The full explanation 404s. What if the container doesn't have curl?